# shader compilation error on const value

Tags: opengl, compilation, constants, fragment-shader

Hi I'm having a bug on a fragment shader that doesn't compile on certain computers. The program using this shader is running on my computer (Quadro K1000M, OpenGl 4.2) but crashes at launch on my friend's computer (AMD Firepro M4100 FireGL V, OpenGl 4.2).

The error is:

```
Failed to compile fragment shader:
Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:2: error(#207) Non-matching types for const initializer: const
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors. No code generated
```

The shader code is as follows:

```
uniform sampler2D source;

const float Threshold = 0.75;
const float Factor   = 4.0;

#define saturate(x) clamp(x, 0.f, 1.f)

void main()
{
    vec4 sourceFragment = texture2D(source, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    float luminance = sourceFragment.r * 0.2126 + sourceFragment.g * 0.7152 + sourceFragment.b * 0.0722;
    sourceFragment *= saturate(luminance - Threshold) * Factor;
    gl_FragColor = sourceFragment;
}
```

I didn't find any info about this error. I asked my friend to edit the shaders to remove the const keyword, the program then worked. But I don't understand why this keyword generates compilation error on his computer since he seems to have the same OpenGL version as I have. I tried to search for known issues between const and shaders but I didn't find anything.

Do you have any idea what's happening ?

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I was thinking of int vs float literals in some older GLSL compilers. I deleted my comment so as not to confuse other people coming to the question.

Comment: I would sincerely avoid writing **0.f** when you do not have a `#version` directive. The single-precision floating-point suffix is not part of GLSL 1.10, and on a strictly compliant compiler it will generate a parse error unless you write `#version 120`.